# strange $_REQUEST behavior on data passed by JQUERY

Tags: jquery, request

I am passing data with Jquery to a php file and all seems to be working well, except that the $_REQUEST array includes an additional item that is throwing me off.

This is the form:

```
<form id = "filter">
 <input class="hook1" type="checkbox" value="115" name="0"> bla blah <br >
 <input class="hook1" type="checkbox" value="116" name="1"> blah blah      <br >
 <input class="hook1" type="checkbox" value="107" name="2"> stil blah blah 
</form>
```

This is the Jquery:

```
 <script>
 $(document).ready(function(){  
 $("#filter").change(function()
 {
var str = $("#filter").serialize();

 alert( str );

 $.ajax({
        url: "filter_trim.php",
        type: "POST",
    dataType:"json",
       data: str,
       success: function(data){
            // do something with returned data
        }
 });
 });
 });
 </script>
```

A var_dump($_REQUEST) using Firebug is printing this for a case of 2 checked boxes, using console from Firebug. VAR_DUMP($_REQUEST)=      array(3) {
      [1]=>
      string(3) "116"
      [2]=>
      string(3) "107"
      ["SQLiteManager_currentLangue"]=>
       string(1) "2"

I have no ideas where this last item is coming from. May be its normal and I am only now seeing it 'cause that's the first time I am passing an array of data.

The php file filter_trim.php initiates like this. As you can see I had to use an array_pop() to get rid of the undesirable last item on the $_REQUEST array.

```
<?php
 $connect = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "root");
 mysql_select_db("cars");
 $trimids = array();
 var_dump($_REQUEST);

 array_pop($_REQUEST);
 $trimids = $_REQUEST;
 $trimids = implode(",", $trimids);
```

I appreciate any input.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should really consider assigning a name to your checkboxes, that way, when you serialise your form, you'll get an associative array that will be easier to work with, something like this:

```
<form id = "filter">
 <input name="hooks[0]" class="hooks0" type="checkbox" value="115">  bla blah <br >
 <input name="hooks[1]" class="hooks1" type="checkbox" value="116"> blah blah      <br >
 <input name="hooks[2]" class="hooks2" type="checkbox" value="107"> stil blah blah 
</form>
```

Then, in your PHP:

```
 $connect = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "root");
 mysql_select_db("cars");

 $trimids = is_array($_REQUEST['hooks']) ? $_REQUEST['hooks'] : array();
```

Comment: Thanks, Evan. The name was already there, though each input had its own. I will try your approach.

Comment: Evan. Your solution does not seem to work. Even though Firebug shows all 3 values as passed when I check them, $_REQUEST keeps only the last checked value. Here is the var_dump() of $_REQUEST:array(2) {
  ["hook1"]=>
  string(3) "107"
  ["SQLiteManager_currentLangue"]=>
  string(1) "2"

Comment: That's how checkboxes work Bernard, if they're all the same name, they will only have one value (the value that is checked). You could try having them with different names, perhaps (hook1, hook2, etc).

Comment: Something that may or may not work is doing "hook1[]" for the name instead of just "hook1" (it works for selects)

Comment: Indeed it works with different names. That's how I had it done originally. If you see my question, my problem is not that but rather the additional item  ["SQLiteManager_currentLangue"]=> string(1) "2" on the array, which messes up handling it. Thanks

Comment: In this case, simple name your checkboxes like hooks[0], hooks[1], etc, and then do `$trimids = $_REQUEST['hooks'];` .. there's no need to be using the entire $_REQUEST superglobal